# How does template specialisation work?

Tags: c++, templates, compilation

Consider the following simple code:

```
template<typename U>
U foo(U a, U b){
    //we don't really care about the body
    return a + b;
}
```

and instantiation:

```
int a = foo(1, 2);
```

I understand that when compiled, foo is specialised and the compiler generates:

```
int foo(int a, int b){
    //we don't really care about the body
    return a + b;
}
```

What is the sequence by which a compiler generates this specialised code?

For instance, I know that if U does not have a '+' operator, then the code will not compile, so some member function table checking is performed, and that a function signature is generated at some point.

Is there a special order for return types, arguments, operations etc to be evaluated?

Comment: "whether it compiles correctly or not"


If it does not compile correctly it will not do any specialisation .

Comment: I have adjusted the question to clarify my intent.

Comment: And have you tried to compile your code?

Comment: [It doesn't compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77f46bd62c24460d).

Comment: It's not about the code, but how a compiler generates code from templates

Comment: A compiler does not gernerate anything from broken code!

Comment: I changed the code to something that will compile. Now please consider the actual question, instead of the example code.

Comment: No, the compiler does not check `a + b` before it selects this template as the one being called. See [this](https://godbolt.org/g/Kz2FM4) and [this](https://godbolt.org/g/BM6gCh)

Comment: Then please explain what does happen

Comment: If you want the full answer, this is too broad. If you want to know how to guide the compiler to the right function, it might be answerable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no specialization, this is instanciation.

Templates are managed in two passes.

The first is almost syntactic; the compiler just verifies if the code looks like something correct.

Then when you use the template (instanciate it) with the given or deduced types, it tries to generate the code (if not already done), so when it encounters `a+b` it just tries to find the appropriate operator for the involved types. If not found, an error is emitted, else code is (eventually, some other errors may happen) emitted.

Comment: So this is prior to compilation? Does the preprocessor handle this?

Comment: No it is the compiler, see standard section **2.2 Phases of translation**. Concepts of *translation units* and *instantiation units*.

Comment: Thank you, I will